# CSS horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css, horizontal-scrolling

I'm trying to create a `<div>` with a series of photos which are horizontally scrollable only.

It should look something like this [LINK](http://cssdesk.com/L6Dsa);

However the above is only achieved by specifying a width for the `<div>` which contains the photos (so they don't 'word-wrap'). If I don't put a width - it looks like this;[LINK](http://cssdesk.com/zLQZ3)

What can I do using CSS to prevent putting in a fixed width as the images may vary.

Thanks

Answer (score 131, accepted):

You can use `display:inline-block` with `white-space:nowrap`. Write like this:

```
.scrolls {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    height: 80px;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.imageDiv img {
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #999;
    margin: 2px;
    max-height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline;/* For IE7*/
    *zoom:1;/* For IE7*/
    vertical-align:top;
 }
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/YbrX3/

Comment: @sandeep plz help me out i used ur css which is in jsfiddle and suppose some data r cuming dynamically by ajax callin which is storing in button which is in footer now how i can scroll that button not window page only footer

Comment: How to also support scrolling by grabbing an image and dragging left/right?

Comment: white-space:nowrap was the answer for me.

Answer (score 15):

Here's a solution with [flexbox](/questions/tagged/flexbox) for images with **variable** width and height:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  margin: 20px;
}
img {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: auto;
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" />
 <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50" />
 <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/5x50" />
 <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x50" />
 <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x100" />
 <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/20x50" />
 <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x30" />
 <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x150" />
 <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x50" />
 <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x350" />
 <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x350" />
 <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" />
 <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50" />
 <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/5x50" />
 <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x50" />
 <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x100" />
 <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/20x50" />
 <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x30" />
 <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x150" />
 <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x50" />
 <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x350" />
 <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x350" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, simple and effective solution.

Comment: Thanks! Much better and more modern solution to the problem, this should be the accepted answer in 2023.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to  generate horizontal scrolling blocks contents.  I got this from here http://www.htmlexplorer.com/2014/02/horizontal-scrolling-webpage-content.html

```
<html>
<title>HTMLExplorer Demo: Horizontal Scrolling Content</title>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#outer_wrapper {  
    overflow: scroll;  
    width:100%;
}
#outer_wrapper #inner_wrapper {
    width:6000px; /* If you have more elements, increase the width accordingly */
}
#outer_wrapper #inner_wrapper div.box { /* Define the properties of inner block */
    width: 250px;
    height:300px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 4px 0 0;
    border:1px grey solid;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="outer_wrapper">
    <div id="inner_wrapper">
        <div class="box">
            <!-- Add desired content here -->
            HTMLExplorer.com - Explores HTML, CSS, Jquery, XML, PHP, JSON, Javascript 
        </div>
        <div class="box">
             <!-- Add desired content here -->
            HTMLExplorer.com - Explores HTML, CSS, Jquery, XML, PHP, JSON, Javascript 
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <!-- Add desired content here -->
            HTMLExplorer.com - Explores HTML, CSS, Jquery, XML, PHP, JSON, Javascript 
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <!-- Add desired content here -->
            HTMLExplorer.com - Explores HTML, CSS, Jquery, XML, PHP, JSON, Javascript 
        </div>
        <div class="box">
             <!-- Add desired content here -->
            HTMLExplorer.com - Explores HTML, CSS, Jquery, XML, PHP, JSON, Javascript 
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <!-- Add desired content here -->
            HTMLExplorer.com - Explores HTML, CSS, Jquery, XML, PHP, JSON, Javascript 
        </div>
        <!-- more boxes here -->
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using table structure, it's more back compatible.
Check this out[Horizontal Scrolling using Tables](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-a-horizontally-scrolling-site/)