# Align images/divs next to each other horizontally without setting the width of the container div

Tags: html, css

Here is my code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
#image_container
{
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    left:0px;
    height:420px;
}
.folder_image
{
    background:url(folder.png) top no-repeat;
    width:679px;
    height:420px;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin-right:50px;  
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="overflow_container">
    <div id="image_container">
        <div class="folder_image"></div>
        <div class="folder_image"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what I am trying to achieve : As and when I add new `divs` with the class `folder_image` , the divs should sit one next to each other horizontally. I know that this can be done by setting the width of the parent container , `#image_container` in my case , but how do I do it without setting the `width` of `#image_container`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And you want horizontal scrolling, right?

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger : you got me! I will try with the scrolling but I am not able to figure out the alignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution :

```
#image_container
{
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    left:0px;
    height:420px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: none;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.folder_image
{
    background:red;
    width:679px;
    height:420px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right:50px;  
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eKW46/

This post helped me : [CSS horizontal scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9925754/css-horizontal-scroll)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
.folder_image
{
    background:url(folder.png) top no-repeat #030;
/*    width:679px;*/
    height:420px;
/*  top:0px;
    left:0px;
    position:relative;
    float:left;*/
    margin-right:50px;  
    display:inline-block;
}
```

[jsFiddle File](http://jsfiddle.net/3xM5t/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `float:left;` to `.folder_image`

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/YnUGb/1/

```
.folder_image
{
    background:url(folder.png) top no-repeat;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    float:left;
    margin:20px;  
}
```

Comment: The divs are coming one below the other in the fiddle example(2 divs in each row),I want them to come next to each other.

Comment: resize the result frame and see.