# Making the Grails Scaffolding list scroll horizontally

Tags: grails

I am trying to display a domain object with a huge number of columns in the grails scaffolding list view. Initially I hit the problem of grails only showing the first 6 members, which was solved by doing "install-templates" and then adjusting the number to show more.

However, the extra elements go off screen with no scroll bar, any idea how to enable it to scroll as part of the scaffolding itself? (I can ofcourse edit the template where required)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you're talking about having the columns paginate, in the same way that your table rows paginate, I think this is more of an HMTL/CSS question than a Grails question.

If so, you could do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9925754/css-horizontal-scroll).

Comment: Fair enough, Too new to grails to realise that. Eventually replaced with a dynamic data table anyways.