# HTML / CSS - Horizontal Scrolling of Images inside Div

Tags: css, image, html, scroll

I've got a number of images inside a div, with the intent of having them lined up horizontally and having the user be able to swipe left/right to pan through the images like a slideshow.

The div has a set width/height, I've set overflow-x: auto, I've set display:inline, etc. etc.

I've tried a variety of combinations of float and display values for the div and the images. I've looked around for answers and tried a bunch, but none seem to work.

I've done it before where I have images in a table, which worked reasonably well, but I figured there has to be a simpler way to do it just through CSS.

Right?

EDIT:
As requested, here is my code.

First I find my original div and clear it, and then the div that will hold the images is created. Then I take "car", which is a JSON object that was passed to the function, and it's "images" key (which is an array of images), and append each image to the imgSlides div.

Here's my JavaScript:

```
var div = document.getElementById("detailsDiv");
div.innerHTML = "";

var imgSlides = document.createElement('div');
imgSlides.setAttribute('class', 'imgSlides');
for(var i=0; i<car.images.data.length; i++){
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    var url = car.images.data[i].image_url;
    img.setAttribute('src', url);
    imgSlides.appendChild(img);
}
div.appendChild(imgSlides);
```

And here's my CSS:

```
#detailsDiv .imgSlides{
width:55%;
height: 55%;
overflow-x:scroll;
overflow-y:hidden;
display:inline;
}
#detailsDiv .imgSlides img{
width:90%;
height:auto;
display:inline;
float:left;
}
```

Any help is much appreciated

Dan

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have only one line you can just add a white-space:nowrap to your style. You can check a similar answer here:

[CSS horizontal scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9925754/css-horizontal-scroll)

If you want to really adapt the content to be able to show as many rows as possible you can use the calc function. You might find a good article on how to do it here:

[Scroll a DIV horizontally using CSS](http://www.kopf.com.br/kaplof/scroll-a-div-horizontally-using-css/)

I hope it helps,