# Need to Programmatically scroll a list of divs horizontally in bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, list, scroll

My client wants a horizontal row of team member pictures that can be scrolled by clicking left and right navigation arrows. What is the preferred way to do this so that it fits in with a responsive grid in bootstrap ? Each image has a header above it and a clickable button below , Hence why I have to have a row/ ul of divs.

Is there a Jquery plug-in, or should I try to create a div that is wider than the screen and use JavaScript to Manipulate the scroll offset ?

Comment: You can achieve this using CSS. Look into this [stackoverflow question][1] for the answer

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9925754/css-horizontal-scroll

Comment: Since you're using Bootstrap, you might as well use the `Bootstrap Carousels` http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

Comment: do you mean have multiple carousels all controlled by one nav ? I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

Wasted ages trying to get carousel hacks to work...

Followed link in answer #1, which shows how to use a wrapper div and css.

I  also  used a css transition to animate the left ( and right) property which I set from an on click handler :-) beer time