# How can I make a group of inline-block elements scroll inside of a div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, overflow

I have a bunch of `<label>` elements in my `<footer>`. Right now, the labels wrap when they exceed the width of the `<footer>`.

How can I make the labels scroll horizontally inside of the footer?

Here is a JSFiddle where the labels are wrapping.
http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/5088/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very simple:

```
footer {
    background: black;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow-x: auto; /* scrollbar only when needed */
}
footer .btn-group {
    font-size: 0; /* eliminates the white space gap between non-floated .btn s */
    white-space: nowrap; /* prevents child inline .btn s from wrapping to the next line */
}
footer .btn-group .btn {
    float: none;
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/5091/

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9925754/css-horizontal-scroll) should help out.  Use:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

to prevent it from starting on a new line, and then:

```
overflow-x: scroll;
```

to make it use a scrollbar.

Comment: Please note that this will force scrollbar even if it doesnt overflow. @Arbel might be better with the auto