# Is it possible to have a horizontal scroll bar

Tags: jssor

Is it possible to have a horizontal navigation bar (while still keeping the arrows) as seen in Amazon.com's slider below?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/e38d7.jpg

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is possible to obtain with only CSS and HTML.

Check it out here: [CSS horizontal scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9925754/css-horizontal-scroll)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you'd write some codes yourself.

```
function OnSliderPositionChangefunction(position, fromPosition) {
  var slidesCount = jssor_slider1.$SlidesCount;
  //value of `position` is in a range from `0` to `slidesCount - 1`
  //now you can calculate the position of navigation bar
}

jssor_slider1.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_POSITION_CHANGE, OnSliderPositionChange);
```

Also, after an user dragged the navigation bar, you can call `jssor_slider1.$GoTo(position);` to sync position of the slider.